# Show a float dialog in any screen?

Tags: android

I want to show a dialog in my android phone anywhere. I want to use windowmanager.addView() 
to come true it. But It doesn't work because this function only can add views.How to show a dialog in anywhere?

Comment: Use Dialog or AlertDialog.Builder to build a dialog. You can then show/dismiss the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this links http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

Allows an application to open windows using the type TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, shown on top of all other applications. Very few applications should use this permission; these windows are intended for system-level interaction with the user.

Constant Value: "android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"

Example projects

https://github.com/fouady/SpotifyTray-Android , https://github.com/henrychuangtw/FB-ChatHead

Comment: Thank you very much. I come true it.

Answer (score 0):

Use code like this (it's from android documentation):

```
// 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

// 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
       .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);

// 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Sorry,i had tested it .it only show in the top of mainactivity . I want to show a dialog in desktop and so on .